XSLT generating only output when no strings are matched
Here’s a snippet of my XSLT code:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:ns1="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FileDesc/v1"
   xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FileRef/v1"
   exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">

   <xsl:import href="File_Download_Functions.xsl"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="File_Properties"/>

   <!-- Root-level template that controls output based on matches -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:choose>
         <!-- Check if there is any match for FileDesc or FileRef -->
         <xsl:when test="/ns1:FileDesc or /ns2:FileRef">
            <!-- Apply templates only if match is found -->
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- No matches, output minimal root element -->
            <empty></empty>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Template for ns1:FileDesc -->
   <xsl:template match="/ns1:FileDesc">
      <xsl:if test="contains(ns1:event_description, '-FLAG-N-FLAG-') and ($File_RType = 'FileCre' or $File_RType = 'FileHdrMod' or $File_RType = 'FileDtlMod' or $File_RType = 'FileDtlCre')">
         <!-- Logic for ns1:FileDesc -->
         ...
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Template for ns2:FileRef -->
   <xsl:template match="/ns2:FileRef">
      <xsl:if test="($File_RType) = 'FileDel'">
         <!-- Logic for ns2:FileRef -->
         ...
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Other templates -->
   <xsl:template name="get_arnotts_location">
      <!-- Logic for get_arnotts_location -->
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="splitStringToLocs">
      <!-- Logic for splitStringToLocs -->
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Issue:
The transformation works fine when there’s a matching template. However, when none of the templates match, an XML file still gets created, which just contains the XML declaration:
tried to add the block with conditions with Root-level 'template that controls output based on matches'

Despite this, an empty output file is still created with only the XML declaration. Is there a way to prevent file creation when no matches are found? Or am I missing something in my approach? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Am I missing any information here?

Which XSLT processor do you use? Do you run the XSLT transformation from the command line or from code (e.g. Java code)? Consider to share that code, also minimal but complete input samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. Your template with xsl:template match="/" has code to output <!-- No matches, output minimal root element --><empty></empty> so I fail to understand why you would get an empty output file with only the XML declaration.

I can see that a document like this <ns1:FileDesc/> would satisfy the when clause in the template which matches /, but then the root element would then not match any of the templates, outputting nothing but the XML declaration.
I suspect what you are trying to achieve with the template that matches / is to return <empty></empty> if none of the other templates match the root element. If I've understood that correctly, then I think you should drop the template that matches / and replace it with this:
<xsl:template match="/*">
   <empty><!-- fallback --></empty>
</xsl:template>

If one of your specific templates match the root element, then the above template will be ignored, but if none of the specific templates match the root element, then the above template will match it. The very general match="/*" attribute automatically gives it a lower priority than any of the templates that match other possible root elements with more specific match expressions.

Hello,
I believe this could fix the issue. I plan to test it in a lower environment first. Since we needed a quick resolution and I wasn’t able to solve it via XSLT, I made changes to the system consuming the XSLT file. Specifically, I added a condition to ignore empty files that only contain the header, which has resolved the issue for now.
Thanks for the feedback!
